# TabHost tabs are not horizontally scrolling when swiping using ViewPager

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, android-tabhost, horizontal-scrolling

I am writing an app that uses many fragments. I have used ActionBarSherlock (with ActionBar). To work-around bug #[240](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/240), I've decided to switch a functionally working implementation to use ActionBarSherlock with **TabHost**.
After half a few hours of work, it is working fine, except for when I am swiping between pages: The correspondent tab is selected, but is **not centered and often not even visible** so the user can't see which tab is selected.

[image]

In the picture you can see the visible fragment ("WEEKLY S..") but the tab is **only half visible**. The next swipe will only make "WEEKLY S..." look like "CALENDAR EVENTS" and I won't know which Tab is selected unless I swipe the TabWidget manually.

Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <HorizontalScrollView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:tabStripEnabled="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

And my TabsAdapter is the same as [Jake Wharton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132047/jake-wharton)'s example of [FragmentTabsPager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabsPager.java).

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650486/tabwidget-wrapped-in-horizontalscrollview-doesnt-scroll-with-viewpager), and to [jucas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/536466/jucas) in particular, I managed to get it to work. Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    View tabView = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(position);
    if (tabView != null)
    {
        final int width = mHorizontalScroll.getWidth();
        final int scrollPos = tabView.getLeft() - (width - tabView.getWidth()) / 2;
        mHorizontalScroll.scrollTo(scrollPos, 0);
    } else {
        mHorizontalScroll.scrollBy(positionOffsetPixels, 0);
    }
}
```

Of course I had to get `mHorizontalScroll` initialized in several places. (If someone isn't sure how to do it, I'll be happy to post the full code.)

Answer (score 0):

I added the code below inside the onPageChangeListener to solve the issue.

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page make respected tab selected
            //actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            View tabView = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(position);
            View mHorizontalScroll = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.mHorizontalScroll);
            if (tabView != null)
            {
                int width = mHorizontalScroll.getWidth();
                int scrollPos = tabView.getLeft() - (width - tabView.getWidth()) / 2;
                mHorizontalScroll.scrollTo(scrollPos, 0);
            } else {
                mHorizontalScroll.scrollBy(positionOffsetPixels, 0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: they asked the full code and I sent mine to explain code. and it works fine.