# Scrollable tabhost

Tags: android, android-tabhost, scrollable

How can I implement a scrollable tabhost like the on in Google PlayStore app?

[image]

Comment: [Here][1] you have, the same question. Use Google next time. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481108/tabhost-tabs-are-not-horizontally-scrolling-when-swiping-using-viewpager

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544162/android-google-play-like-tabs?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) widget and setting mode to scrollable.
Example #1

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

or in code
Example#2:

```
tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Google's [SlidingTabLayout](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html) to display a custom [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) title strip as used in Google I/O Android App .For your exact requirement please check sample git demo [Android Material Design Template with Material Tabs (SlidingTabs) and Material Navigation Drawer](https://github.com/hutilicious/MaterialRohling) .I hope it will helps you a lot.