# Tab touch did not work while horizontal swipe gesture works in FragmentTabHost

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, swipe-gesture, fragment-tab-host

I have implemented horizontal swipe gesture Fragment TabHost in Fragment Activity and it works fine. But Tab touch did not work.

Source code here: https://github.com/babumirdha/FragmentTabSwipeExample

The Source Code is below :

MainFragmentActivity.Java

```
public class MainFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
     OnPageChangeListener, OnTabChangeListener  {
private FragmentTabHost host;

    private ViewPager pager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tab_host);

            pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    host = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    host.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabFrameLayout);

    TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("tab1");

    spec.setIndicator("First tab");
    host.addTab(spec,FragmentTab.class, null);

    spec = host.newTabSpec("tab2");

    spec.setIndicator("Second tab");
    host.addTab(spec,FragmentTab.class, null);

    spec = host.newTabSpec("tab3");

    spec.setIndicator("Third tab");
    host.addTab(spec,FragmentTab.class, null);  

            host.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(this));
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

    int pageNumber = 0;
    if (tabId.equals("tab1")) {
        pageNumber = 0;
    } else if (tabId.equals("tab2")) {
        pageNumber = 1;
    } else {
        pageNumber = 2;
    }
pager.setCurrentItem(pageNumber);

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int pageNumber) {

    host.setCurrentTab(pageNumber);

}


}
```

fragment_tab_host.xml

```
 <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager  
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   android:id="@+id/pager"  
   android:layout_width="match_parent"  
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>  

</LinearLayout>
```

MyPagerAdapter.Java

```
   public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private Context ctx;

public MyPagerAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    return container;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return (view == object);
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
}
 }
```

FragmentTab.Java

```
 public class FragmentTab extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_layout, container, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv.setText(this.getTag() + " Content");
    return v;
  }
 }
```

page_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can how can i add swipe gesture here?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Check out similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650486/tabwidget-wrapped-in-horizontalscrollview-doesnt-scroll-with-viewpager which might help you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will fail because `FragmentTabHost` is a widget designed to manually work with fragments(along with corresponding tabs). This means that you can't combine it with a `ViewPager` because the `FragmentTabHost` will add the fragments directly to a container while the `ViewPager` manages the fragments through an adapter(like yours, but with an implementation that actually does something). Right now the `FragmentTabHost` adds it's own internal layout and the `ViewPager` will end up on top of the actual content. This is why you are able to swipe and change the tabs(because, although you swipe an empty `ViewPager`, you have a `OnPageChangeListener` set on it to change the tabs). You can't click the tabs because the `ViewPager` on top eats the touch events(you can swipe on top of the tabs to see that they do get changed through the same `ViewPager`).

So, use a `ViewPager` along with a normal `TabHost`, there are countless tutorials on how to do this.

Comment: Yap I got many tutorials about normal TabHost But I need FragmentTabHost with tab click & swipe. Is there any alternative to ViewPager that can be used with FragmentTabHost for both tab click & swipe.

Comment: @BabulMirdha I've told in my answer why you can't use the `FragmentTabHost` with a `ViewPager`. Is there a reason why you require the `FragmentTabHost`?

Comment: I got your answer but I was searching alternative of ViewPager.
Yap, I have a reason to use FragmentTabHost. In my app I used navigation drawer. When I click on an Item from drawer item, it displays a FragmentTabHost with 2 or 3 tabs where need both click & swipe. It is almost like YouTube App. Here a url of demo app https://github.com/babumirdha/NvDrawerListWithFragmentTabHost.

Comment: @BabulMirdha The Youtube app(at least the last version) doesn't use a `FragmentTabHost`(it isn't using a `TabHost` either). Even so you don't need that widget. Check this sample code https://gist.github.com/luksprog/8820045 copy the whole files(and replace) to your current project and you'll see what you want.

Comment: I implemented that code successfully. Thanks @Luksprog.

Comment: Swipe navigate work successfully in my project but I faced a problem to transfer data between tabs. There are three tabs: SourceTab, DestinationTab and TransferTab in Transaction. It can pass data from SourceTab to TransferTab but it can't pass data from DestinationTab to TransferTab. Here is the git Url: https://github.com/babumirdha/NvDrawerListWithTabHostDataPassSwipe. Plz help!

Comment: @BabulMirdha See https://gist.github.com/luksprog/8956228 , your correct code updates the String in the transfer tab but you never refresh the view to actually show the text. Also, please start new questions, you're out of the scope of the current question.

Comment: I posted a new question for it. here is the url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746143/how-to-passing-data-from-one-fragment-tab-to-another-fragment-using-tabhost .Thanks